# can't connect to azure sql server from ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, ubuntu

I am getting the following error when trying to access my azure sql server from terminal using the command

```
tsql -H 'myserver.database.windows.net' -U 'myuser' -P 'mypass'
```

Error:

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Error 20017 (severity 9):
        Unexpected EOF from the server
        OS error 115, "Operation now in progress"
Error 20002 (severity 9):
        Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

also tried using settings in freetds.conf but same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you're using [TDS version 7.4](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/tdshistory.htm). Make sure tsql is up to date (you will very likely have to [download, build and install from sources](https://martinrichards.tumblr.com/post/28488121620/connecting-to-sql-azure-using-freetds)) and then force the version from env:

```
TDSVER=7.4 tsql -H 'myserver.database.windows.net' -U 'myuser' -P 'mypass'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqlcmd as well.

```
sqlcmd -S 'myserver.database.windows.net' -U 'myuser' -P 'mypass'
```

for configuring sqlcmd use url:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017